# Negative margin on css hover causing jitter

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want this button to have a border around it on hover (as seen on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcPVj/)). It actually does what i want it to do, but it jitters way too much on Chrome and Firefox (IE10 seems to work perfectly).

What's the cause of this, and how can i approach a solution that wont jitter during the transition?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="round_bt_container">
        <div class="round_bt" style="background-image:url(http://edinhopiscinas.com.br/img/img1.png);background-size:160px;background-position:center center;background-repeat:no-repeat;">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
        width:80%;
        height:80%;
        position:absolute;
        padding:10%;
        background-image:url(http://edinhopiscinas.com.br/img/bg.jpg);
    }
    .round_bt_container{
        cursor:pointer;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        margin-right:40px;
        border-radius:50%;
        border:5px solid #ffffff;
        box-shadow:2px 1px 15px -9px #000000;
        width:160px;
        height:160px;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease;
        -o-transition:all 0.2s ease;
        transition:all 0.2s ease;
    }

    .round_bt{
        position:absolute;
        border-radius:50%;
        width:160px;
        height:160px;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        border:0px solid #eeeeee;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease;
        -o-transition:all 0.2s ease;
        transition:all 0.2s ease;
    }

    .round_bt img{
        border-radius:50%;
    }

    .round_bt_container:hover .round_bt{
        width:160px;
        height:160px;
        border:5px solid #f98523;
        padding:15px;
        margin-left:-20px;
        margin-top:-20px;
    }

    .round_bt_container:hover{
        border:2px solid #ffcfa7;
        margin-left:3px;
        margin-top:3px;
    }
```

Comment: Changing the padding on the #container from percent to pixels (or ems) helps in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/zcPVj/17/

Comment: Yeah, but FF and IE10 still jitter with this solution.

Comment: checkout my second edit

Comment: Works like a charm! exactly what i wanted. Accepeted your answer, though it lacks some explanation on what exactly you did, and why it works.

Comment: essential I separated the components that are animated so that the image is not affected when morphed

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate the ring from the image itself:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="round_bt_container">
        <div class="inner_ring"></div>
        <div class="round_bt" style="background-image:url(http://edinhopiscinas.com.br/img/img1.png);background-size:160px;background-position:center center;background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
        <div class="ring"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ring {
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0px solid #eeeeee;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    transition:all 0.2s ease;
}

.round_bt_container:hover .ring{
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    border:5px solid #f98523;
    padding:15px;
    margin-left:-20px;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zcPVj/22/

edit: i've added a second ring

Comment: Ah works in Chrome but not FF, the 5px border to 2px is making it jitter still. Easiest thing to do is to just make the hover 5px, otherwise make another ring div.

Answer (score 0):

Got your original fiddle and HTML working with some revisions:

Added cross-browser box-sizing to the circles (this allows you to use the actual width, without having to add or subtract the margins and padding), they are great.

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Removed the width on .round_bt and changed them to percentages

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

Here is your updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zcPVj/21/

Comment: As much as this works, it doesn't have the functionality i was expecting it to have. I really need that padding between the outer border and the inner element. If you take my original code and just remove the transitions, it will give you the exact result i'm looking for (only without the transition itself, wich is the only problem i'm having).